# Смена центра карты по клику на заголовок меню

Tags: jquery, api, javascript

Добрый день.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможность смены центра карты по клику на заголовок меню.

Сайт, чтобы нагляднее: http://bm.webbys.ru/kontakty/

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Пример с panTo()](http://jsfiddle.net/kd0esdvu/)

[Пример с setCenter()](http://jsfiddle.net/kd0esdvu/1/)

API карт версии 2.1, но думаю, что setCenter  будет работать и с предыдущими версиями.

Подгрузка подлагивает, потому что слишком быстро перемещается, у panTo() вроде нет настройки скорости, но для плавного перемещения можно использовать вот такой вариант: http://jsfiddle.net/kd0esdvu/2/

Comment: Спасибо, а возможности прогрузки слоя карты до перемещения нет?

Comment: Подгрузка подлагивает, потому что слишком быстро перемещается, у panTo() вроде нет настройки скорости, но для плавного перемещения можно использовать вот такой вариант: http://jsfiddle.net/kd0esdvu/2/

Answer (score 0):

https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#setCenter

Comment: Функцию эту видел, не совсем понимаю, как при клике отдать параметры центра этой функции. Опыта мало.

Comment: @Роман20, проще всего записать конкретные координаты в элемент и подтягивать их. При желании можно осуществить [поиск по геокоду](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/geocode-docpage/) (адресу).